# How do you fully suppress the output of f2py?

Tags: python, numpy, f2py

I'm using f2py to interface between python and a fortran code. I'm using the fortran code to generate data for training a neural network, so eventually I may have to run the code and f2py up to 10 million times. Every time I use f2py it produces around 15-20 lines of output, which ends up bloating the standard output file and is possibly slowing things down.

I've tried using the "--quiet" flag mentioned in the official documentation and I've tried re-directing the output to a file or /dev/null which have reduced the amount of output but hasn't eliminated it completely.

**Is there any way to suppress the output completely?**

I'm using anaconda3/2019.10 and the intel compiler suite version 19.0.

The basic bash shell command I'm using is:

```
python -W ignore -m numpy.f2py -c -m python_rk4 --fcompiler=intel --f90flags='-g -w' --opt='-O0' --include-paths /path/to/my/data --quiet py_rk4_in.f90  2>&1 >/dev/null
```

The typical output looks like (this warning appears 4 times):

```
In file included from /software/spackages/linux-centos8-x86_64/gcc-8.3.1/anaconda3-2019.10-v5cuhr6keyz5ryxcwvv2jkzfj2gwrj4a/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h(12),
                 from /software/spackages/linux-centos8-x86_64/gcc-8.3.1/anaconda3-2019.10-v5cuhr6keyz5ryxcwvv2jkzfj2gwrj4a/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h(4),
                 from /local_scratch/pbs.131339.pbs02/tmphkx4m82n/src.linux-x86_64-3.7/fortranobject.h(13),
                 from /local_scratch/pbs.131339.pbs02/tmphkx4m82n/src.linux-x86_64-3.7/fortranobject.c(2):
/software/spackages/linux-centos8-x86_64/gcc-8.3.1/anaconda3-2019.10-v5cuhr6keyz5ryxcwvv2jkzfj2gwrj4a/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h(84): warning #2650: attributes ignored here
                      NPY_CHAR NPY_ATTR_DEPRECATE("Use NPY_STRING")
```

The output seems to be python warnings which the `-W ignore` flag should take of, but that doesn't seem to work. I'm pretty new to python, so I'm not sure if I'm doing this right. This is my first time posting, so apologies if I've broken etiquette. Thanks for the help!

Comment: redirect both stdout and stderr to `/dev/null` . You need `> /dev/null 2>&1` in that order -- your attempt with `2>&1 >/dev/null` will not succeed in redirecting stderr to `/dev/null`

Comment: This is no python warning. I don't know details of f2py, but this looks like compilation warnings from some process that is called by python.

Comment: Thank you for the help @alaniwi! That worked!